# Should I use Core Data for iOS To-Do App?

Tags: ios, core-data, synchronization

The title sort of sums it up... I am making a to-do list application with Xcode 8 and am not sure whether to use Core Data or not. I want to integrate a sync feature so if a user logs in with Facebook or Google then it can sync to their profile for use on other devices and am not sure if this will conflict with Core Data. I am completely new to app development so not too sure about these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Data is a very powerful framework, but it is also an advanced framework with a pretty steep learning curve.

If you expect to have large to-do lists and want to be able to search, sort, create links between different types of items, etc, then you might need the power of Core Data.

If you think you could structure your app so that the entire ToDo list is saved/read all at once, then you might want to look at a simpler method for storing it.

You might look at using NSCoding to serialize your data object and save it to/read it from a file. Or, if you can set up your data model using property list objects (arrays, dictionaries, numeric values, dates, strings, and Data) then you could save it as a property list.

If you're just getting started with app development then trying to tackle Core Data right away might make your head explode. You might want to start out with a simpler approach to ease into it, and perhaps refactor the app to use Core Data later. Look at creating a separate data model class that abstracts the way you save your data from the rest of the app so that it would be easy to refactor it later. That's good Object-Oriented design in any case.

Comment: I agree 101% with your answer even after 5 years of solid iOS experience I found Core Data is one of the hardest frameworks to learn, especially under the multithreaded environment.